# Firefox/Chrome Linux vs Windows issue

Tags: firefox, 14.10, google-chrome, browser

Ok so here is the problem that got me looking at this.

Recently Battle.net closed their "website bug forum" for the Diablo 3 forums. In its place the put two buttons at the bottom of the page next to the red Blizzard logo. In linux I have tried Firefox and Chrome but neither show those buttons.

I recently installed virtualbox with Windows 7 lately for a certain program that doesnt run on WINE so I opened up IE. Sure enough the buttons are present in IE. Then I installed Firefox on Windows 7. The buttons appeared there too!

This isnt just one computer either. I have another laptop with the same exact problem.

So, what is the issue? Why is it on Windows that things are working normally but on linux they arent?

edit:

link to Diablo 3 forums - https://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/

flashversion shown in "about:plugins"

```
File: libflashplayer.so
Path: /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so
Version: 11.2.202.442
State: Enabled
Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202
```

Comment: Could you add a link to the page, and do you have flash player installed?

Comment: edited main post with link to D3 forum. i also have flash installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an OS or a plugin problem. Use the HTTP version of the site (http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/) instead of HTTPS. Why? Because their JavaScript says so:

```
<script xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Feedback.showForm = false;
if (window.location.protocol === 'http:') {
Feedback.showForm = true;
}
//]]>
```

Comment: that sounds like it would be less secure since its not using "https:" however that does actually show them now.

Comment: @David now that you have access to these buttons, use them and ask them. :)